# How can I plot a histogram of comparisons over time?

Tags: r, ggplot2, compare, bar-chart, histogram

I need to observe the leaf area under the two treatments (WW and WS) for a long time, so I want to draw a histogram comparison chart over time, but I don't know how to put the two bars of two treatments in one graph.

The data is as follows:

```
cd<-structure(list(Pos_heliaphen = c("Y12", "Y13", "Y20", "Y21", 
                                     "Y34", "Y35", "Y42", "Y43", "Z06", "Z07", "Z22", "Z23", "Z36", 
                                     "Z37", "Z44", "Z45", "Y12", "Y13", "Y20", "Y21", "Y34", "Y35", 
                                     "Y42", "Y43", "Z06", "Z07", "Z22", "Z23", "Z36", "Z37", "Z44", 
                                     "Z45"), traitement = c("WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WS", 
                                                            "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WS", 
                                                            "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WS", "WW", "WW", "WS", "WS", "WW", "WS", 
                                                            "WW", "WW", "WS"), Variete = c("Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", 
                                                                                           "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", 
                                                                                           "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", 
                                                                                           "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", 
                                                                                           "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", 
                                                                                           "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica", "Angelica"), 
                   Date_obs = structure(c(19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 
                                          19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 19135, 
                                          19135, 19135, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 
                                          19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145, 19145
                   ), class = "Date"), SF_Plante_Totale = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67589.64, 71868.33, 69883.2, 
                                                            73892.79, 72106.38, 82228.68, 73393.92, 63867.78, 70127.46, 
                                                            64710.27, 76991.58, 75486.69, 80237.34, 74250.9, 68804.73, 
                                                            63714.6)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                          "data.frame"))
```

The code I used is as follows (There are redundant operations because my original data has more "variete"):

```
df<-subset(cd, Variete %in% c("Angelica"))
options(scipen=200)
df$Date_obs <- as.Date(df$Date_obs)



df %>% 
  select(1,2,3,4,5) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("SF")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value,group=Pos_heliaphen)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="steelblue") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")+
  facet_wrap(~Pos_heliaphen,drop=TRUE)+
  labs(y=expression(paste('Original total leaf area (mm'^2,')')))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

And I got the figure as below:

[image]

But I want to compare the two bars circled together in one graph (One is WW, the other is WS).
Like this graph below. Then only 8 graphs left in the end.

[image]

Because right now is just the beginning of observation, so we don't really have time line. But the two figures below are from last year. I just don't know How to put the WS and WW of the same day in one figure.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "histogram comparison chart over time"?  Is that a separate histogram by date? Can you draw a picture? The example you pointed to doesn't have a time component, does it?

Comment: @Jon Spring Please see the update! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you wanted but

```
df %>% 
  select(1,2,3,4,5) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("SF")) %>%
  mutate(w = substr(Pos_heliaphen, start = 1, stop = 2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value,group=traitement, fill = traitement)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")+
  facet_wrap(~w,drop=TRUE)+
  labs(y=expression(paste('Original total leaf area (mm'^2,')')))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

## New

```
df %>% 
  select(1,2,3,4,5) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("SF")) %>%
  mutate(w = substr(Pos_heliaphen, start = 1, stop = 2)) %>%
  group_by(Date_obs, w) %>%
  filter(!(sum(value) == 0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value,group=traitement, fill = traitement)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Pos_heliaphen), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size = 2, vjust = -0.5) +
  ylim(c(0, 90000)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")+
  facet_wrap(~w,drop=TRUE)+
  labs(y=expression(paste('Original total leaf area (mm'^2,')')))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(title = "Angelica")
```

[image]

## add

```
df<-subset(dff, Variete %in% c("Angelica"))
options(scipen=200)
df$Date_obs <- as.Date(df$Date_obs)
  
df <- df %>% 
  select(1,2,3,4,5) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("SF")) %>%
  mutate(w = substr(Pos_heliaphen, start = 1, stop = 2))
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(w, Date_obs) %>%
  summarize(ww = paste0(Pos_heliaphen, collapse = "-"))
df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("w", "Date_obs")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date_obs, value,group=traitement, fill = traitement)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  ylim(c(0, 90000)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")+
  #xlim(c(as.Date("2022-05-23"), as.Date("2020-06-02"))) +
  facet_wrap(~ww,drop=TRUE)+
  labs(y=expression(paste('Original total leaf area (mm'^2,')')))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 

  labs(title = "Angelica")
```

Comment: Exactly! But I think the title of each graph has problem. Can it be adjusted to what I draw as edited? Thank you! @Park

Comment: @Chouette There are three plots and I guess second one is what you want. What should be the title? Can you give me an example for `Y12` and `Y13` case? There is no title for second one. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Yes! The second one! I hope Y12 and Y13 and so on can show up above the bar, like what I drawed in the second graph. Then maybe one big title "Angelica" in top left is OK. Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: And is it possilbe to show all dates? Because the measurement day is 02/06/2022, but it didn't show up. Sorry to bother you!

Comment: @Chouette I add the code and plot above. Pleach check it out.

Comment: Can the date 2022/5/23 also be showed up? I had two dates in the original data.

Comment: @Chouette Simply removing `filter(....)` part will show up that date, but as there is value 0, it might seem pretty weird and need to adjust `position_dodge` and ect on `geom_text` part.

Comment: So sorry to bother you again, but is it possible to keep the text for the last two bars in graph? As you can see in the last figure I edited, the same text show up in every bar, it looks not very tidy... Or, is it possible to add "Y13-Y12" just in the facet title?

Comment: @Chouette This may be the final response to this question. After then, you'd be better make another question or find out yourself. I add the code above.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'll pay attention to the way to ask for help next time! Anyway, you really did me a big favor! Wish you all the best!